# How a get LINKS without image?

Tags: javascript, css

I have html code

```
<a href="#link1"><img src="image1"></a>
<a href="#link2"><img src="image2"></a>
<a href="#link3"><img src="image3"></a>

<a href="#link4">THIS TEXT, LINK NAME</a>
<a href="#link5">THIS TEXT, LINK NAME</a>

<a href="#link2"><img src="image2"></a>
<a href="#link3"><img src="image3"></a>
```

I need

> ```
> <a href="#link4">THIS TEXT, LINK NAME</a>
> <a href="#link5">THIS TEXT, LINK NAME</a>
> ```

How get links without image ? With CSS selector or JS selector?

Comment: Phrase your question properly please.

Comment: CSS doesn't have a parent selector so you'll need to use JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    var myList = []
    var all = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for(var i = 0 ; i < all.lenght; i++) {
      if(all[i].innerHTML == 'YOUR TEXT') {
        myList.push(all[i]);
      }
    }
```

Comment: var myList = []
    var all = document.querySelectorAll("a");
    for(var i = 0 ; i < all.length; i++) {
      if(all[i].querySelector("img") === null) {
        myList.push(all[i]);
      }
    }`

Answer (score 0):

To select it using javascript, you can do

```
var linkList = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

for(i=0; i< linkList.length; i++){ 
   if(linkList[i].getElementsByTagName("img").length == 0){
      console.log(linkList[i]);
   }                            
}
```

Refer : http://jsfiddle.net/kfrmqzot/

As CSS does not have parent selector, you can not achieve this directly.
You can wrap the text inside a span tag and select it.

Answer (score -1):

try this `$("a:not(:has(>img))")`

Comment: Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': 'a:not(:has(>img))' is not a valid selector.